Finite element method for 3D built-up structures using two materials
I wish to do finite element calculations of a steel structure supported on rubber blocks. As a warm up problem I make an all steel structure as follows.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 1.0; (*Length of cylinder*)
r = 0.1;  (* Radius of cylinder*)
w2 = 0.12;(* Half width of supports*)
h = 0.1;(* Full height of supports*)
h2 = 0.05;(* Support height under cylinder *)
tk = 0.05; (* Thickness of suports *)

cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {Len, 0, 0}}, r];
sup1 = Cuboid[{Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {Len/5 + tk, w2, h - (r + h2)}];
sup2 = Cuboid[{4 Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {4 Len/5 - tk, w2, 
h - (r + h2)}];
Graphics3D[{cyl, sup1, sup2},
Axes -> True]


The blocks under the cylinder are meant to be rubber but for now I am going to use steel. Make the mesh:
geom = RegionUnion[cyl, sup1, sup2];
mesh = ToElementMesh[geom];
mesh["Wireframe"]


Next define the parameters, variables and that this is a solid mechanics problem. Then I calculate the vibration properties (eigenvalues and vectors). The latter takes about 10 seconds.
pars = <|"YoungModulus" -> 210  10^9, "PoissonRatio" -> 3/10, 
"MassDensity" -> 7850, "AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>;
vars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}};
ps = SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
SolidFixedCondition[z == -r - h2, vars, pars];
Timing[{vals, vecs} = 
NDEigensystem[{ps == {0, 0, 0}, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
 wall]}, {u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, 
t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 4];]

Now look at the eigen shapes

These look about right. So far so good. How to include the supports as rubber?
Start of full problem
I start as before but work with OpenCascade
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 1.0; (*Length of cylinder*)
r = 0.1;  (* Radius of cylinder*)
w2 = 0.12;(* Half width of supports*)
h = 0.1;(* Full height of supports*)
h2 = 0.05;(* Support height under cylinder *)
tk = 0.05; (* Thickness of suports *)

cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {Len, 0, 0}}, r];
sup1 = Cuboid[{Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {Len/5 + tk, w2, h - (r + h2)}];
sup2 = Cuboid[{4 Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {4 Len/5 - tk, w2, 
h - (r + h2)}];

I make the supports as separate components and join everything up
supA = RegionDifference[sup1, cyl];
supB = RegionDifference[sup2, cyl];

shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[supA];
shape3 = OpenCascadeShape[supB];

faces1 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape1];
faces2 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape2];
faces3 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape3];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{faces1, faces2, faces3}]];

bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]


Careful examination of the mesh shows that there is a boundary between the supports and the cylinder. This should enable the material geometry to be modelled properly.
The Youngs Modulus of rubber should be about 1.0*10^6 with a Poisson Ratio of 0.4 and a mass density of 1500 but I don't know how to put these in. Looking at other posts it is suggested that a Piecewise construction is preferred but that does not seem possible here.  How do I proceed? I could not find a 3D example in Help.
Thanks

welcome back to FEM...
The multi material section seems relevant for this. Here is how I'd do it.
We start in exactly the same way you did:
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Len = 1.0; (*Length of cylinder*)
r = 0.1;  (*Radius of cylinder*)
w2 = 0.12;(*Half width of supports*)
h = 0.1;(*Full height of supports*)
h2 = 0.05;(*Support height under cylinder*)
tk = 0.05; (*Thickness of suports*)

cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {Len, 0, 0}}, r];
sup1 = Cuboid[{Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {Len/5 + tk, w2, h - (r + h2)}];
sup2 = Cuboid[{4  Len/5, -w2, -(r + h2)}, {4  Len/5 - tk, w2, 
    h - (r + h2)}];

supA = RegionDifference[sup1, cyl];
supB = RegionDifference[sup2, cyl];

shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[cyl];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[supA];
shape3 = OpenCascadeShape[supB];

faces1 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape1];
faces2 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape2];
faces3 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape3];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{faces1, faces2, faces3}]];

bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];

Now, I set up a helper association. This will make the code more readable:
material = <|"Rubber" -> 1, "Steel" -> 2|>
(* <|"Rubber" -> 1, "Steel" -> 2|> *)

We insert markers into mesh:
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{RegionCentroid[cyl], 
      material["Steel"]}, {RegionCentroid[sup1], 
      material["Rubber"]}, {RegionCentroid[sup2], 
      material["Rubber"]}}];
mesh["Wireframe"]


And check that the markers are present:
mesh["MeshElementMarkerUnion"]
(* {1, 2} *)

We visualize the individual material groups:
parts = Map[
  mesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == #[[1]], 
     "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#[[2]]]]]] &, {{material[
     "Rubber"], Black}, {material["Steel"], Gray}}]


And visualize the combination:
Show[parts]


Now, to the actual question:
vars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}};
pars = <|
    "YoungModulus" -> Piecewise[{
      {210*10^9, ElementMarker == material["Steel"]},
      {1*10^6, ElementMarker == material["Rubber"]}}],
   "PoissonRatio" -> Piecewise[{
      {3/10, ElementMarker == material["Steel"]},
      {4/10, ElementMarker == material["Rubber"]}}],
   "MassDensity" -> Piecewise[{
      {7850, ElementMarker == material["Steel"]},
      {1500, ElementMarker == material["Rubber"]}}], 
   "AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>;

Set up the equation just like you did:
ps = SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
  SolidFixedCondition[z == -r - h2, vars, pars];

Get the eigenvalues and functions:
numEigen = 4;
AbsoluteTiming[{vals, vecs} = 
   NDEigensystem[{ps == {0, 0, 0}, 
     Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall]}, {u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z],
      w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, numEigen];]

Compute the frequencies:
eigenfrequencies = Sqrt[vals]/(2 \[Pi])
(* {2.41738, 2.92912, 3.40086, 6.16735} *)

Visualize the result:
GraphicsGrid[Partition[MapThread[Show[
     mesh[
      "Edgeframe"[
       PlotLabel -> Style["freq=" <> ToString[#1] <> " Hz", 8]]],
     deformedMesh2 = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, #2];
     deformedMesh2["Edgeframe"],
     deformedMesh2["Wireframe"[
       "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
        Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[LightGray]]]]
     ] &, {eigenfrequencies, vecs}], numEigen/2]]


What you be helpful for me to know, is what you tried to figure this out and why you could not find the solution. Where did you look in the help, what would you have expected to find where? That way I can try to improve the documentation.

Thank you excellent answer as usual. Where did I look? 1) I started with the Finite Element Method User Guide and found Element Meshes with Subregions. At the end of that section there was a good link that stated "Additional information about how to create material regions in three dimensions can be found in the OpenCascadeLink." 2) The Open Cascade Link got my subregions but was misleading in that it did not deal with material regions and materials. 3)  found a section on markers but not linked to materials. In the past I had found how you set up a single material (can't remember from  where)

...continued. I could not find an example of the form you demonstrate here. It would be good to have a 3D example like this in Help. As far as I can see there is no reference to materials in the Finite Element Method User Guide.  Hope that helps.

...continued. I never found the multiple material section in Solid Mechanics page. Not sure why. Perhaps it would help to have the subsections at the start of the section. If I had found that I would have gone further I suspect.

Thank you Hugh. That is very valuable information for me. So if I understood correctly you where missing the information that you could specify "YoungsModulus" -> Piecewise. I have done a few things. 1) For version 14.1 many of the monographs got a table of content that is deeper than what we used to have. It's a bit of a hack, but it's much better then before I think. 2) For version post 14.1 I added paragraphs in the sections that you mention that link to multi material simulations or how to find them.

One other piece of information that I need to bring across better is that if you go to the PDEModels Overiew page you will find guide pages for each field of physics. On those guide pages, for example the SolidMechanics guide page you can scroll to the Models Overview section and find a table with features each of the models has.
